# Requiring user input in order to run a script which controls Safari

Tags: applescript, safari, script

Using Script Editor, I've created the following script to close tabs and open a particular window:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with i from (count of windows) to 1 by -1
        repeat with j from (count of tabs of window i) to 1 by -1
            set thistab to tab j of window i
            set foo to name of thistab
            if foo is not equal to "bar" then close thistab
        end repeat
    end repeat
    do shell script "open -a Safari 'https://www.google.com/advanced_search'"
end tell
```

Works fine, but when I save it as an application, it requires the user to allow it to work, which ruins my functionality.
The error message displayed is:

> "Tabulator app" wants access to control "Safari". Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in "Safari", and to perform actions within that app.

Is there anyway to override this message within the script?

Comment: Oops. Sorry - the script formatting went away when I posted.  It should look like this:
tell application "Safari"
 repeat with i from (count of windows) to 1 by -1
  repeat with j from (count of tabs of window i) to 1 by -1
   set thistab to tab j of window i
   set foo to name of thistab
   if foo is not equal to "bar" then close thistab
  end repeat
 end repeat
 do shell script "open -a Safari 'https://www.google.com/advanced_search'"
end tell

Comment: mega4m, I've removed the P.S. as it is not relevant to the main issue and this site works best with one question per question. Feel free to post a separate question to address the second issue.

Comment: No - current systems require explicit permission for an application to command other applications via scripts.  The dialog will only be shown once for each application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Just for clarification - when you say "once for each application," do you mean once in total on that system or once every time the script runs?
My plan was to set something up for the script to run every 24 hours at a particular time, but I'm wondering if a solution to my problem would be to have the script always running in the background and have something built into it that would trigger the close tabs action every 24 hours.
That way, I could grant permission on setup and only have to worry about it in the event that the computer is restarted (a rare event).

Comment: The system puts up the permission dialog one time only when the application is first run.  Note that since AppleScript saves properties and globals by modifying the script file, it should be code signed or made run-only to avoid losing the permission if the app is changed.

Comment: I'm getting the permission dialog every time I run the app. I've tried saving as "run only" but it still never fails to throw up that dialog.